# Need help to Split the below HTML text file in two parts using linux scripting

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting

I have a html main.txt file, I need help to split it in two parts.
headpart.txt and bodypart.txt.

Below is my html main.txt text file - Original

```
<p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><table><tbody><tr><th><p>Name</p></th><th><p>Creation Date</p></th><th><p>ID</p></th><th><p>Comments</p></th></tr><tr><td><p>Ubuntu-18.04</p></td><td><p>Thu Sep 15 12:20:42 UTC 2022</p></td><td><p>12345</p></td><td><p>this_is_a_custom_comment</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Ubuntu-18.04-16437838</p></td><td><p>Thu Sep 15 12:40:06 UTC 2022</p></td><td><p>56789</p></td><td><p>custom_comment</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Ubuntu-18.04-2343</p></td><td><p>Thu Sep 15 13:03:04 UTC 2022</p></td><td><p>9876</p></td><td><p>custom_comment</p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
```

After split headpart.txt -

```
<p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><table><tbody><tr><th><p>Name</p></th><th><p>Creation Date</p></th><th><p>ID</p></th><th><p>Comments</p></th></tr>
```

Part 2 - bodypart.txt

```
<tr><td><p>Ubuntu-18.04</p></td><td><p>Thu Sep 15 12:20:42 UTC 2022</p></td><td><p>12345</p></td><td><p>this_is_a_custom_comment</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Ubuntu-18.04-16437838</p></td><td><p>Thu Sep 15 12:40:06 UTC 2022</p></td><td><p>56789</p></td><td><p>custom_comment</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>Ubuntu-18.04-2343</p></td><td><p>Thu Sep 15 13:03:04 UTC 2022</p></td><td><p>9876</p></td><td><p>custom_comment</p></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
```

========
I need help to split the main.txt to headpart.txt and bodypart.txt using shell script

Comment: If it's one file why do not use editor? If it's about many files clarify the criteria how to split.

Comment: I need to automate it using shell scripting

Comment: In such case define the criteria for splitting